# where do I put log4j.xml weblogic eclipse

Tags: java, maven, log4j, weblogic

I work with java 1.6, Eclipse Juno, weblogic 10.3.6, Maven.

I want to configure log4j in my project . I added log4j dependencies in pom.xml. I configured log4j.xml

But when I deploy my project from eclipse using weblogic server, log4j doesn't start. In the console I don't see log4j messages.

I believe that is a place log4j.xml problem

How do I have to configure log4j in server weblogic?

My project has the following structure

[image: Project Structure]

My pom.xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>eusurveyadmin</groupId>
    <artifactId>eusurveyadmin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <!-- <scope>compile</scope> -->
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

log4j.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN" "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    Appenders
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %c - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="info" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="C:/temp/logs/esurveyadmin-info.log" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="4096KB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="20" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="Threshold" value="Info" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}-%-4r [%t] (%F:%L) %-5p %c %x - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="error" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="C:/temp/logs/esurveyadmin-error.log" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5120KB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="20" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="Threshold" value="Error" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}-%-4r [%t] (%F:%L) %-5p %c %x - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <category name="org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper">
        <priority value="off"/>
    </category>

    <logger name="com.eusurveyadmin.controller">
        <level value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="error" />
        <appender-ref ref="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="eusurveyadmin.daos.implementacion">
        <level value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="error" />
        <appender-ref ref="info" />
    </logger>
<!-- 3rdparty Loggers -->
    <logger name="org.springframework.core">
        <level value="warn" />
        <appender-ref ref="error" />
        <appender-ref ref="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.beans">
        <level value="warn" />
        <appender-ref ref="error" />
        <appender-ref ref="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.context">
        <level value="warn" />
        <appender-ref ref="error" />
        <appender-ref ref="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.web">
        <level value="warn" />
        <appender-ref ref="error" />
        <appender-ref ref="info" />
    </logger>


<logger name="org.hibernate">
        <level value="warn" />
        <appender-ref ref="error" />
        <appender-ref ref="info" />
    </logger>

    <!-- Root Logger -->
    <root>
        <priority value="warn" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" /> 
        <appender-ref ref="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="error" />
    </root>


</log4j:configuration>
```

Do I have to configure anymore?

I read other posts and I have pom.xml dependencies, log4j.xml.

Comment: the file log4j.xml is a resource and should be unter `src/main/resources`

Comment: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html

Answer (score 0):

To make your log4j configuration work it should be on your classpath under `/WEB-INF/classes` directory.
To make Maven include your `log4j.xml` in the final `war` file under this path, maven expect it to be placed inside one of its resources directories.

As @jens mentioned, to include `log4j.xml` in your web application, place it in your project's `/src/main/resources/` directory or define your own resources directory and by using Maven's `<resources>` tag.